# quilt patch with a new file

Tags: patch, quilt

I'm trying to create a new quilt patch with only one file added. Unfortunately the file seems to be ignored.

I did `quilt new some_patch` and `quilt add some_file`. I can see the file in `quilt files` then, but when I refresh, I get back:

```
Nothing in patch some_patch
```

After I pop some_patch, the added file is not removed and nothing is actually saved into the patch (patch file is not created).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to add the file to quilt first, before writing it. So that quilt can track the difference. If you add it after writing it, there is no change after that.

Answer (score 2):

Move new files aside, "add" names of files, then move files back.

```
$ quilt files |while read filename; do quilt remove "$filename"; mv "$filename" t; quilt add "$filename"; mv t "$filename"; done    
$ quilt refresh   
$ quilt diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you should add the file before changing it, otherwise, you will not the difference, once there will be no difference between the time you added it and the time you run the diff. That is what the quilt diff shows.