# How to add a new file in a folder using quilt patch technique?

Tags: openwrt

I want to add a new file inside asterisk-chan-dongle-13 in LEDE(openwrt). For that how can I write a patch file(quilt) to add a new file inside a folder like asterisk-chan-dongle-13?

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work? Show us your code and where it failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [quilt patch with a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499130/quilt-patch-with-a-new-file)

Comment: Let me be brief, i am having asterisk-chan-dongle-1.1-20170913.tar.gz ,this will get enable when I select asterisk-13 in LEDE .Now I want to add a new file inside the chan-dongle (for example-pwm.c and pwm.h) to add these files inside the asterisk how can I do a QUILT patch for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can unarchive your source code, then move into the source directory and run:

```
quilt new 001-name_of_your.patch
```

This will create new patch in your environment (it will create a directory named *patches* in which quilt will store all the patches). After that you must add your new file to the patch running:

```
quilt add my_file.patch
```

At this point you can edit the file. You can check the modifications to the file using:

```
quilt diff
```

When you're finished you can update the patch file with:

```
quilt refresh
```

You will find your updated patch in the *patches* directory.